# extracting xml root element name using xpath in camel route is not working

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

`.log(LoggingLevel.INFO,  xpath("name(/*)").getText())`

in camel Route is printing as `-- name(/*)`

but I am expecting the root element name.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, the Log EIP only supports the simple language for logging details from the message. Instead you can extract the xpath root name to a header, with setHeader("xxx", xpath...) or something and then log the header via Log EIP.

Also next time I suggest you spend more time to make your question more detailed, many people wont know what you ask for, only users with years of Camel knowledge may see a bit what you try to ask.